# Can't connect to database (10061)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi, mariadb, heidisql

I have a Raspberry Pi (first model) I use as a server. I followed a tutorial and installed Apache2, MySQL, Phpmyadmin etc.

I have also set up a ddns for my home network to be able to connect to it wherever I am, and of course forwarded the necessary ports.

At first everything worked wonders.

- I could connect to the database using phpmyadmin by navigating to `adress/phpmyadmin`from any network.
- I could also use HeidiSQL to connect to the database, again from any network.

The MySQL version I had at this time was v5.5. I wanted a feature available on v5.6 but this version was not available on my RPi (ARMv61). Instead it seemed like MariaDB should do the trick. So I updated to MariaDB using the command:

`sudo aptitude install mariadb-server`

Now I am not able to connect through HeidiSQL anymore, Phpmyadmin still works though from any network just like previously. Trying to connect with HeidiSQL I get the output (no matter what username/password i try):

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'adress' (10061)'

`mysql -V` gives output:

> mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.27-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv7l) using readline 5.2

My RPi info is

> Linux redface 4.4.26+ #915 Thu Oct 20 17:02:14 BST 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux

The user privileges are available in the image below

[image]

How can I connect to the database again using HeidiSQL? Have I missed something with the user privileges?

With phpmyadmin I use the username `root`

Comment: Yeah...as you can see now your installation is more secure....there is no more `root`@`*` user, so you can't connect to you database from any ip...in order to accomplish that you need to create an user based on the client that want to connect to your raspberry server(the machine that got Heidi Installed)...can you provide that local ip?

Comment: @Hackerman but isn't root@% synonymous with root@*, as % means any in phpmyadmin interface? And also, I can connect though phpmyadmin even if I am not local. The purpose for me is to be able to connect from any IP, not just a selected few. I am in bed now, can provide local IP tomorrow.

Comment: % means a synonymous for localhost, 127.0.0.1and ::1

Comment: **This is not a permissions issue.**  The code `(10061)` is `WSAECONNREFUSED` -- Connection refused. Not to be confused with "access denied."  No service is listening on the target IP address and port.  MariaDB is not listening on `0.0.0.0:3306`.  `mysql -V` only tells you the installed *client* version -- it doesn't tell you anything about the MariaDB server.  Check the config for a commented-out [`bind_address=0.0.0.0`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bind_address).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I can't believe I missed that when I was googling! Thank you. Make it an answer and I will accept it. The file in which I needed to make the change was `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This particular error is not about permissions.**

The code `(10061)` is WSAECONNREFUSED -- a *Windows* socket error code for `Connection refused,` not to be confused with "access denied."

Connection refused typically means no service is listening on the target IP address and port. MariaDB is not listening on 0.0.0.0:3306.

mysql -V only tells you the installed client version -- it doesn't tell you anything about the MariaDB server.

Access to phpMyAdmin doesn't tell you anything, either, because with it, you're not talking to the database server remotely -- you're talking to your web server remotely, and your web server is running code that talks to the database *locally* from within the same machine, and often uses a different mechanism of server access that is not TCP/IP.

Check the config file for a commented-out [`bind_address=0.0.0.0`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bind_address) or similar.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/